# Reset macOS application security alert

Tags: macos, cocoa

When downloading an app from the internet, usually you get a dialog that asks if you want to open it and if it is signed and/or notarized.

Now I already opened my app once, so the dialog doesn't appear again.

How can I reset the system so I can see what a user would see that downloaded the app for the first time?

Comment: The SecAssessment system policy tool (`spctl`) is rumored to be able to do this, but I've never had much luck in figuring out how to get it reverse the decision for a single app. If you do find out, please post the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a bug in `spctl` or what but it doesn't seem to be able to remove a rule based on a path.  I always get the error: "{app path}: no matches for search or update operation"

:-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I think I got it figured out, but it's a little odd (I had to delete the app and re-extract it from the .zip archive for the app I test downloaded from the internet).

So my comment from above still applies - the easy way to remove the rule allowing the app by path doesn't seem to work:

> I'm not sure if it's a bug in spctl or what but it doesn't seem to be
>   able to remove a rule based on a path. I always get the error: "{app
>   path}: no matches for search or update operation" :-/

However the other way to refer to rules is to use their "rule number" and the `--rule` parameter.  To find the rule number I had to use a command that doesn't appear to be documented in the --help output or the man page:  `--list`

```
spctl -v -v -v -v --list -t execute
```

lists all the execute rules and you can see the rule (usually at the top of the output) for your app.  The rule number is at the far left before the "[" that is for the label or group.

You can then delete the rule via

```
spctl -v -v --remove --rule 5417
```

(replacing 5417 with the rule for your entry, obviously.

Then if you do `spctl -v -v --raw -a --path "path to your app"` then you will see that the `assessment:verdict` key is now false.

The thing that is odd is that when I then immediately launched the app, 10.13.6 at least, it still launches without the dialog... :-/  I'm thinking this is a caching situation because after I deleted the app and re-extracted the app it still launched.

But after I emptied the trash and launched some other app and then came back and extracted this app and launched it again I got the expected your policy doesn't allow this app to launch dialog.

Give that a try and see if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks! Yes it works. I have to delete the app, empty the trash and re-download it though (like you said). I am on 10.14.3

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @james-bucanek, unfortunately I found no simple solution, like a terminal command. But what seems to work is to **create a new user account**. It's a bit tedious, but at least I can check again if the app is properly notarized.

You can also check for notarization via terminal command `spctl -a -v MyApp.app`, but just to be safe.

[image]